# App crash on Reactive Cocoa subscribe [UIButton rac_signalForControlEvents:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

App crashes when on subscribe method when uibutton called and gives the following error in stack.

```
   ncaught exception: +[NSDate act_secondsSince1970]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10dd06e08
   2016-10-06 23:05:36.594 Mamabear[32867:217553] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
   2016-10-06 23:05:36.773 Mamabear[32867:217563] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIProperty' for entity 'GAIProperty'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
   2016-10-06 23:05:36.774 Mamabear[32867:217563] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'GAIHit' for entity 'GAIHit'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
   2016-10-06 23:05:37.701 Mamabear[32867:217449] -[UIButton rac_signalForControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f81a296c850
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

(lldb)

App crashed on that line. See below:

```
    [[_loginButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
 subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     [[MBAnalyticsHTTPClient sharedClient] capture:[AnalyticsModel initWithContext:@"welcome_to_mamabear" action:@"log_in_as_guardian"]];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check library search path in build settings.

Comment: Thanks i will tried to make  change search path settings.